# object is none after saving modal form

Tags: django, django-forms

i am using django forms for my product model but the instance is returned as None

```
if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method =='POST':
            form = ProductModelForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                instance = form.save()
                product = instance.save()
                print product
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("DataEntry"))
            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("DataEntry"))

        else:
            form = ProductModelForm()

            context = {
            'form' : form , 
            'products' : Product.objects.all().order_by('-timestamp')
            }
            return render(request, "products/dataentry.html", context)
```

what might be the issue over here?
need help

Comment: `save()` method doesn't returned the saved instance. Also, why are you doing `instance.save()` again, after `form.save()`?

Comment: how can i get the saved object?

Comment: Just print the `instance`, `form.save()` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `form.save()` returns the instance. In your case, you are not using `form.save(commit=False)`, so there is no need to save the instance.

Unlike `form.save()`, `instance.save()` returns `None`, so you are currently assigning `None` to product.

You can simplify the code to:

```
        if form.is_valid():
            product = form.save()
            print product
```